# Mostrar un ticket con lo seleccionado según checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, json

Haber como detallo todo esto sin dejarme nada.

Tengo un div con una imagen de un rostro:

```
<img src="images/zonasHifu/facial.svg" alt="" id="lipoCuadro" class="fotoFacial">
```

Otro div con distintos checkbox:

```
                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuadrante superior
                    <label for="CuadranteSuperior" class="switch2">
                       <input id="CuadranteSuperior" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuadrante Superior">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuadrante inferior
                    <label for="CuadranteInferior" class="switch2">
                       <input id="CuadranteInferior" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuadrante Inferior">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuello y papada
                    <label for="CuelloPapada" class="switch2">
                       <input id="CuelloPapada" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuello y papada">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Escote
                    <label for="Escote" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Escote" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Escote">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>



                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Papada
                    <label for="Papada" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Papada" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Papada">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuello
                    <label for="Cuello" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Cuello" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuello">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>
```

Y otro div donde muestro los value de los checks que me hace una suma en plan ticket de compra.

Esto es para según los checks me muestre el ticket:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var precios = new Map();
    precios.set("Cuadrante Superior", "10");
    precios.set("Cuadrante Inferior", "10");
    precios.set("Cuello y papada", "30");
    precios.set("Escote", "30");
    precios.set("Facial completo", "30");
    precios.set("Papada", "30");
    precios.set("Cuello", "30");

    $(":checkbox").change(function () {
        // defines un arreglo
        var selected = [];
        $(":checkbox[name=opciones]").each(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                // agregas cada elemento.
                selected.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        if (selected.length) {
            $('#resvahifu').empty();
            $("#precioTotal").empty();
            $("#precioTotal").html("0");
            $.ajax({
                //cache: false,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json', // importante para que
                data: {
                    'selected': JSON.stringify(selected)
                }, // jQuery convierta el array a JSON
                url: "getZonas.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                        let precioProducto = precios.get(item); //aqui pondrias el precio de producto verdadero
                        $('#resvahifu').append(
                            $(document.createElement('li')).text(item)
                        );

                        //Aqui te simulo la suma del precio total
                        $("#precioTotal").html(parseInt( $("#precioTotal").html()) + parseInt(precioProducto))
                    });
                }
            });
            // // esto es solo para demostrar el json,
            // // con fines didacticos
            // //alert(JSON.stringify(selected));

        } else
            alert('Debes seleccionar al menos una opción.');
        if (selected.length == 0) {
            //además no dejo desmarcar si solo queda un check
            this.checked = true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Getzonas.php:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    //$string = file_get_contents('./string.json');
    $data = $_POST['selected'];
    //var_dump($data);
    $json = json_decode($data);
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Ahora me muestra el value del check pero necesito que me muestre por ejemplo:

Cuadrante superior        60€
Cuadrante inferior        20€

TOTAL: 80€

Eso por un lado, gracias a un compañero de aquí, cuando seleccionamos el check de facial completo y estan seleccionados otros como cuadrante superior se tiene que activar el check de facial completo y desactivar si hay uno o varios activados que son estos: cuadrante superior, cuadrante inferior, papada, papada + cuello y cuello y a la inversa también, si esta facial completo y selecciono cuello por ejemplo se desactive el facial completo.

Ahora más o menos funciona pero al activar facial completo me duplica los resultados en el ticket y al seleccionar por ejemplo cuello si facial completo esta marcada no se desmarca.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Facialcompleto').change(function(){
      if($('#CuadranteSuperior').prop('checked'))
        $('#CuadranteSuperior').click();
      $('#CuadranteSuperior').attr('disabled', this.checked);
      if($('#CuadranteInferior').prop('checked'))
        $('#CuadranteInferior').click();
      $('#CuadranteInferior').attr('disabled', this.checked);
      if($('#CuelloPapada').prop('checked'))
        $('#CuelloPapada').click();
      $('#CuelloPapada').attr('disabled', this.checked);
      if($('#Cuello').prop('checked'))
        $('#Cuello').click();
      $('#Cuello').attr('disabled', this.checked);
      if($('#Papada').prop('checked'))
        $('#Papada').click();
      $('#Papada').attr('disabled', this.checked);
    })
  })
```

Pongo una foto del desarrollo para ver si se entiende mejor

[image: la apariencia del desarrollo]

No se si lo he explicado bien :S

Comment: No se si fue por la extensión de tu pregunta o que pero casi no entendí :c

Comment: No se como poder explicartelo mejor si mostrarlo! @Bender Paisa dime que no has entendido y te explico mejor

Comment: He subido una foto para entender mejor el desarrollo @BenderPaisa

Answer (score 1):

Había algunos problemas en el código, por ejemplo la sección para marcar y desmarcar opciones debía ejecutarse dentro de la función `change()` de los checkbox, también la parte donde se consulta a una función ajax no era necesaria si su única función era la de transformar el resultado a json, por ultimo haciendo algunos ajustes se puede mostrar la lista de elementos seleccionados mas el total y que cambien si se marca la opción `"Facial completo"`.

En síntesis este es el resultado:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var precios = new Map();
    precios.set("Cuadrante Superior", "10");
    precios.set("Cuadrante Inferior", "10");
    precios.set("Cuello y papada", "30");
    precios.set("Escote", "30");
    precios.set("Facial completo", "30");
    precios.set("Papada", "30");
    precios.set("Cuello", "30");

    $(":checkbox").change(function () {
      if(this.id=='Facialcompleto'){
        if($('#CuadranteSuperior').prop('checked'))
          $('#CuadranteSuperior').click();
        $('#CuadranteSuperior').attr('disabled', this.checked);
        if($('#CuadranteInferior').prop('checked'))
          $('#CuadranteInferior').click();
        $('#CuadranteInferior').attr('disabled', this.checked);
        if($('#CuelloPapada').prop('checked'))
          $('#CuelloPapada').click();
        $('#CuelloPapada').attr('disabled', this.checked);
        if($('#Cuello').prop('checked'))
          $('#Cuello').click();
        $('#Cuello').attr('disabled', this.checked);
        if($('#Papada').prop('checked'))
          $('#Papada').click();
        $('#Papada').attr('disabled', this.checked);
      }
      
      // defines un arreglo
      var selected = [];
      $(":checkbox[name=opciones]").each(function () {
          if (this.checked) {
              // agregas cada elemento.
              selected.push($(this).val());
          }
      });
      $('#resvahifu').empty();
      $("#precioTotal").text(0);
      if (selected.length) {
          $("#precioTotal").empty();
          $("#precioTotal").html("0");
      
         let precioFinal = 0;
         for(h=0;h<selected.length; h++){
           item=`${selected[h]} (${precios.get(selected[h])})`;
           precioFinal=precioFinal+Number(precios.get(selected[h]));
           $('#resvahifu').append(
                 $(document.createElement('li')).text(item)
           );
         }
         //la suma del precio total
         $("#precioTotal").text(precioFinal);

      } /*else
          alert('Debes seleccionar al menos una opción.');
      /*if (selected.length == 0) {
          //además no dejo desmarcar si solo queda un check
          this.checked = true;
      }*/
      return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Facial completo
                    <label for="Facialcompleto" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Facialcompleto" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Facial completo">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>
<li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuadrante superior
                    <label for="CuadranteSuperior" class="switch2">
                       <input id="CuadranteSuperior" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuadrante Superior">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuadrante inferior
                    <label for="CuadranteInferior" class="switch2">
                       <input id="CuadranteInferior" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuadrante Inferior">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuello y papada
                    <label for="CuelloPapada" class="switch2">
                       <input id="CuelloPapada" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuello y papada">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Escote
                    <label for="Escote" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Escote" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Escote">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>



                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Papada
                    <label for="Papada" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Papada" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Papada">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuello
                    <label for="Cuello" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Cuello" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuello">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>
Ticket de Zonas:
<div class="resvahifu" id="resvahifu"></div>
Total:
<span id="precioTotal" class="spanPrecio">0</span>
```

Espero que resuelva tu problema, saludos.

Comment: Esta estupendo ahora funciona correcto!! pero falta que en la lista de cosas seleccionadas salga el precio al lado, pero no se como ponerlo ya que en el value no queda bien. Y que si lo mismo que pasa con facial completo que desactiva lo demás tendria que estar a la inversa tambien, puedes ayudarme @the-breaker

Comment: @Miguel puedo ayudarte con lo del precio, pero no entiendo bien eso del facial

Comment: Gracias! pues lo de facial es: Si tenemos seleccionado papada, cuadrante superior, cuadrante inferior (ejp) y seleccionamos facial completo, esos tres se deselaccionan por que el completo ya coge esas zonas. Pero si tenemos seleccionado facial completo y seleccionamos (ejp) papada, se tendria que desactivar el facial completo y activarse papada @the-breaker